# "data manipulation operation not legal on this view" happening in a user table

Tags: oracle

This error is happening when I'm trying to insert values on a table belong to the user which I'm using:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

In all the places the people say that it occurs when trying to insert/update/delete on a view, but it is certainly a table, and the user has the privileges needed.

So, there is any other cause for this happening beyond trying to do ilegal operation with a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would activate SQL tracing and try the insert again, then look at the trace file to determine exactly what SQL statement is causing the error.

If, as suggested by others, it is SQL executed by a trigger against some other object, you'll see that in the trace as recursive SQL and it will be clear what object is involved.

If there is no recursive SQL in the trace, then it is likely that you are not accessing the object you think you are, and the trace should show the actual object ID being used, which you can check against the data dictionary.

If it really is just a table, and there is no recursive SQL involved, then it sounds like you have a case for Oracle support.

Comment: Thank you, i never had did this. I don't know exactly why this occured, but it's not a table, as you say, But a materialized view, but the script which to create it look like a normal table declaration. In the sql developer it's shown it as a table. So, thank you very much. I'm sorry the question didn't explain exactly what I need, I'm begginer on oracle and in sql in general. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative answer: I came across this error when I tried to INSERT a record into a materialized view table.

Comment: It took a while to realize that the table I tried to insert into, actually belonged to a materialized view..

Answer (score 3):

First thing: are you *really* sure it is a table?  From the way you have framed the question it might be that the user experiencing this problem doesn't own the table.  In which case, perhaps there's a synonym or something which is really pointing at a view.

Second thing it might be, is if there's a trigger on the table and it is the action it fires causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, yes, i'm really sure it is a table. I try do this with a lot o users, including the schema, and after this I give privileges for the others users try to isert but it didn't work. Its not a synonym, but, I'm working with Oracle SQL Developer, and the tool can't got the sql code of the table, may be it mean that the table is corrupted or anything like this? Thank you

Comment: Thank you, you were right, it was not a table. It was a materialized table, but how it's has been show between the other normal tables and not between the views, the materialized views or between the synonyms, I think that were a table. I just don't understand why it's organized as a table by the sql developer. I'm sorry the inconvenient, i'm begginer on sql and in oracle. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThiagoMelo - I almost include " or A Materialized View" at the end of the first paragraph.  Wish I had now :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a super old post, but FYI, the "table" is actually a materialized view (mview). The mview is not configured to allow for updates and you therefore cannot insert/update/delete on it.

You can get a list of all of your materialized views by running:

```
select * from user_mviews
```

Comment: add one more point: if you want to change the data in an MV, you can use the "for update" clause like this: create materialized view mv for update as select * from t;

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are most likely looking at a materialized view and **not a table**. Search for

```
Select * from user_objects
```

in the dictionary to see the object type.

Answer (score 1):

one more thought...

try it with an explicit identification on the table like this:

```
insert into myschema.mytable () values ()...
```

just in case there is another one locally..

Answer (score 0):

Another case to issue this error is when you are trying to update data using a column that does not exists:

```
update house set color = 'blue' where street = 'ABC';
```

> `street` column does not exists in table `house`

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not perform deletes on materialized views, you will need to delete the data from the table that is pushed that updates the materialized views, then refresh those tables.

example:
I want to delete data from Table 1 and Table 2 which are Materialized views. Currently, the data for these 2 tables are pushed from table 3. I will need to delete the data from table 3, then refresh the view for tables 1 and 2.

This data should no longer be present in tables 1, 2 and 3 after a refresh of the views.

Hope this helps in 2020!