# SQL .Error in view command

Tags: mysql

I have created two tables and merge them using view.I am unable to update the view table. Update command is not working.It arises an error as  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view".

```
SQL>UPDATE library 
SET bookno=176 WHERE rackno=33;
```

Here library is the view name.
can anyone give me an answer?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["data manipulation operation not legal on this view" happening in a user table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444956/data-manipulation-operation-not-legal-on-this-view-happening-in-a-user-table)

Comment: not the same @Bayrem your link tagged as oracle and this is tagged as MySQL

Comment: I checked before flagging for duplicate, that error message is specific to oracle.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html

> For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship
>   between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table.
>   There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.
>   To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the
>   following:
>
> Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
>
> DISTINCT
>
> GROUP BY
>
> HAVING
>
> UNION or UNION ALL